# Are Master Documents still unreliable in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, chapters

In previous versions of Microsoft Word, many expert have reported that Master Documents can easily corrupt the linked documents. Is this still the case in Word 2016.

I have separate documents for each chapter of a book I am writing. I would like to make a Master Document for the whole book. Is that dangerous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation not to use master document has not changed, and holds for Office 2016: http://www.addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm